# I want to post a pdf document using simpleposttool to Solr. What command should is use

Tags: solr, lucene

For posting a XML document I used the below command

```
java  -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/Hanu_Core/update -jar .\post.jar .\money.xml
```

Comment: What problems or errors did you encounter? As it stands, your question is quite broad and difficult to answer.

Comment: If you are on a recent Solr and NOT on Windows, have a look at bin/post tool instead. It runs post.jar under the covers, but it a bit more user-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your title, I assume, you maybe asking for "Commands" to post pdf using SimplePostTool.

In the CLI you can type as below to check all the available properties and options.

```
$ java -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar -h
```

Moreover, you may follow like the example as below

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/pdfs/update/extract -Dcommit=yes -Dtype=application/pdf -jar exampledocs/post.jar ~/solr-4.10.3/solr-app/solr_home/pdfs/pdfs_res/Apache_Solr.pdf
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anis Suggested You can use `-Dtype=application/pdf`. can also use `-Dauto`

Example :

```
java -Dauto -Dc=collection_name -jar post.jar pdf_file.pdf
```

Using -Dauto we can index all document format that tika supports.

i.e txt,doc,docx,pdf,xml,html etc.

For more details hit help command
`java -jar post.jar -h`